# Computionally efficient vertex enumeration for (convex) polytopes

Tags: algorithms, discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes, computational-geometry, polyhedra

Let $P \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ be an $\mathcal{H}$-polytope. The *vertex enumeration problem* asks for the set of vertices $V$ of $P$. Theoretically, the vertex enumeration problem for $P$ can be performed in $\mathcal{O}(|V|^{\lfloor d/2 \rfloor})$, cf. [[1]](http://www.mathematik.tu-darmstadt.de/~pfetsch/Publications/polycomplex.pdf).
Practically, one would use the *double description method*, cf. [[2]](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.45.8343&rep=rep1&type=pdf), and cf. [cddlib](http://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/fukudak/cdd_home/) for an implementation of the former.

In my application, I have to solve a rather large number of such vertex enumeration problems in let's say dimension $10$. Unfortunately, *ccdlib* is too slow and causes numerical problems (the GMP version is even slower).

Moreover, for my application it suffices to find a superset of $V$. Hence, I thought there might be a way to decompose $P$ into "simpler" polytopes such that the vertex enumeration for each such polytope could be performed much faster.

Is anybody aware of such method?

Comment: How is the polytope defined?  Is it given as an intersection of half-planes?  If so, can this problem be transformed to the dual problem of enumerating all the facets of the convex hull if the vertices are given?

Comment: Yes, it is an $\mathcal{H}$-polytope, i.e., intersection of finitely many affine half-spaces. Yes, the facet and the vertex enumeration problem are strongly polynomial equivalent.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

cddlib is rather old; a much more efficient implementation of the double description method is in PPL (Parma Polyhedra Library). One frontend to PPL can be found in Sagemath: http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/geometry/sage/geometry/polyhedron/constructor.html
PPL will perform computations exactly.

Apart from the double description there is the reverse search, a method consisting of "walking" over the vertices, implemented in lrs: [http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~avis/C/lrs.html](http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/%7Eavis/C/lrs.html)
and it might work better for your problems.

More info on double description and reverse search methods can be found in Komei Fukuda's [Polyhedral FAQ](https://cddlib.github.io/polyhedral_faq/)

Comment: PPL gives wrong results in high dimensions: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2286233/is-there-reliable-polyhedra-library

Comment: No, it's not giving wrong results there - please see the answer to your question I just posted.

Comment: Do you know of a resource that explains either the double description method or the reverse search method from a pedagogical standpoint?

Comment: @Makogan - I've added a link in the answer to such a resource.